# Extract parallel text from Wikipedia dumps

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, wikipedia

In my research project I need to extract parallel documents from Wikipedia dumps. In other words, I have downloaded the English and Italian Wikipedia dumps. Now, I want to parse them and for each article in the English dump, find its translation in the Italian dump (should be done by the Interlanguage links), and store them in the same file to do some cross-lingual text processing afterward.

I searched a little bit for this, but I couldn't find any code for this purpose. But, since I have seen many papers in which the authors have done the same, I thought it might be worth asking first, before inventing the wheel from scratch.

Any idea is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I am trying to do the same (after a couple of years, lol), and the APIs seem quite slow for the full encyclopedia. What solution did you use in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Use this Wikipedia api, [action=query&query=langlinks](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Blanglinks)

Example:
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=langlinks&lllang=it&titles=Calculus|Bread|Biology

The response gives the corresponding Italian articles.